# Gatsby - adding npm modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby

​Can one easily add NPM modules to Gatsby.

Eg:

```
gatsby new lumen https://github.com/wpioneer/gatsby-starter-lumen 
cd lumen 
npm install react-router-component-transition --save

├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.3.1 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-addons-css-transition-group@^0.14.0 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-router-component@>=0.27 
└─┬ react-router-component-transition@0.2.0   
  └─┬ object.assign@4.0.4
    ├─┬ define-properties@1.1.2
    │ ├── foreach@2.0.5
    │ └── object-keys@1.0.11
    └── object-keys@1.0.11

npm WARN react-router-component-transition@0.2.0 requires a peer of react-router-component@>=0.27 but none was installed. 
npm WARN react-router-component-transition@0.2.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN react-router-component-transition@0.2.0 requires a peer of react-addons-css-transition-group@^0.14.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN gatsby-starter-lumen@1.1.0 No repository field.
```

​I tried and got some peer dependency errors.

Comment: Are you using NPM 2? It blocks installing modules w/ unmet peer dependencies.

Comment: Also it looks like `react-router-component-transition` only works with React 0.14?

Comment: Thanks for these tips, has helped me get my bearings. Gatsby is amazing btw.

Answer (score 0):

Also these are just warnings Gatsby packages are not usually on bleeding edge if thats what you are running for npm and node.